# Bootstrap 3 table, set fixed column width in px with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a table with fixed column widths in px on my Bootstrap 3 project. Every `<th>` in my table `<table id="items" class="table table-striped table-condensed">` has `style=##px` but its not assigning it. I've tried adding `style="width:auto; overflow: scroll;"` to the table but it does't work. Also tried removig every class on my table but colums wont grow.

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could specify a `<colgroup>` section:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1">
        <col span="1">
    </colgroup>
    ...
</table>
```

... and then set the width of your columns in CSS:

```
col {
    width:200px;
}
```

If you are using the bootstrap `.table` class on the table element, you will also need to set the width of your table to `auto`.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nuhxj/131/).

Comment: This fiddle didn't use bootstrap at all. If you add bootstrap, you would find your fiddle does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 applies a `width: 100%` to the `<table class="table">`. In order to honor this, the browser will stretch cells to fill the remaining space. In Chrome 35 (I haven't tested in anything else), rules seem to be:

1. If some columns are fixed, but not all, then the fixed column widths are honored, and the remaining width of the table is split between the remaining columns that have no specified width.
2. If all `<col>` or `<colgroups>` have a specified (fixed) width, the browser will **attempt** to treat the widths like a percentage proportional to the width of the table. So if a two col's in a table have 100px, and 200px widths respectively, they **may** get 33% and 66% of the width respectively. This is not always the case the case though. The rules for this behavior seem to be quite complex and are probably browser-specific.

See this fiddle for a few examples and some experimentation.

http://jsfiddle.net/bzuillsmith/Nuhxj/129/

Answer (score -3):

The solution finally was to remove 'table' class from the `<table>`. That way you can specify de width on `<th>` by css or directly on its width attribute. With the table class the width of the column can't be set even specifying a `<colgroup>` like a suggested answer.

Comment: This isn't actually true and it's not _really_ using Bootstrap 3 tables. Setting the width or even "class='col-sm-4'" works on <col> tags with Bootstrap 3. Kevin's answer works.