# removing bootstrap class 'table' from table tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been creating a website, where table's - first column needs to have a specific width so user could see as many as preceding column in mobile view. I tried every thing to make first column of fixed width and failed, until I found solution on following stackoverflow ticket given by wencha:

[Bootstrap 3 table, set fixed column width in px with scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992799/bootstrap-3-table-set-fixed-column-width-in-px-with-scrollbar)

I removed bootstrap class 'table' from html and I could give desired width to first column. Could anyone please answer, what does this bootstrap 'table' class do in webpage and what could be the difference if removed from the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used for the styling of the bootstrap CSS module for tables.

> For basic styling—light padding and only horizontal dividers—add the
>   base class .table to any `<table>`.

[Bootstrap Tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

So if you remove it, the table will simply not style in the bootstrap style.

Comment: Many thanks Sebsemillia for the information. Also learnt, that removing 'table' class turns 'white-space: nowrap' into 'white-space: default'. Which makes table to expand till content width instead to '.container' width in desktop view too. Thanks to media queries to control this for mobile devices.